# No route match location

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

I am using spring boot with React.Can I know why it shows the error No route match location?

**App.js**

```
 <Routes>
 <Route path="/" element={<Layout/>}>
 <Route path="/" element={<Home movies={movies} />} ></Route>
 <Route path="/Trailer/:ytTrailerId" element={<Trailer/>}></Route>
 </Route>
 </Routes>
```

**Trailer.js**

````
const Trailer = () => {

    let params = useParams();
    let key = params.ytTrailerId;
    return (
      <div className="react-player-container">
        {(key!=null)?
          <ReactPlayer controls={true} playing={true} url ={`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${key}`} 
          width = '100%' height='100%' />
          :null}
      </div>```
````

Comment: Why do you have two routes for the same path? Also, this error indicated that your url doesn't match any routes

Comment: @konrad what you mean by two routes. I only route Trailer to youtube. I want to let this link http://localhost:3000/Trailer/d9MyW72ELq0 play the youtube url mentioned in <ReactPlayer />